# Flex 4 - Pass data sent by HTTPService object to result handler

Tags: flex4, httpservice

I have a data object that gets sent as a POST request by an HTTPService object, but I want to be able to access the data object in the result handler. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var token:AsyncToken = httpService.send();
token.yourPropertyName = yourObject;
```

AsyncToken is a dynamic object so you can add properties at runtime.
Then, in your result handler, you acces the token with :

```
event.token.yourPropertyName
```